# How to add user level environment variables to be used by GUI linux application?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

What is the recommended way to add user level environment variables to be used by a GUI application (binary of a wxPython application) in linux (Ubuntu)? I know there are ~/.bashrc, ~/.cshrc, ~/.profile etc for console apps.

1. Where can I add new paths to existing PATH?
   (/bin:/usr/bin/:/usr/X11R6/bin/usr/local/bin)?
2. How to add settings as new key value pairs? This is meant to be used by a bunch of applications.

Answer (score 0):

1. PATH and some other variables are stored in /etc/environment
2. In my opinion, the best place for settings is /etc/.APPNAME/conf or ~/.APPNAME/conf